# Restore old version of build path in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, git, buildpath

I have a Java application which works with Kafka and Spark Streaming. In the attempt to clean the build path, I messed it up and I don't manage to bring it how it was before.
Is it possible to restore an old version of the build path?
I have several versions of my project on GitHub, but can I do this with Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse stores the build path details as xml in a file called ".classpath"

If you track changes to that file in your GitHub project, you should be able to restore back to a previous version of the file. Assuming an appropriate version is at commit a1b2c3, use something like:

```
git checkout a1b2c3-- your/project/path/.classpath
```

See the [Git checkout page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) for more info.